# Statistical Calculus In Big Data Set Wrong Values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, jupyter

I am using the following code to make a small example of a function I intend to use on a big data set.
I calculate statistical features incrementally for each `ID` in which the unit is month.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[58685991,'2020-06-01',2],
                   [58685991,'2020-06-01',1],
                   [58685991,'2020-06-01',0],
                   [58685991,'2020-12-05',7],
                   [57839709,'2020-12-01',5],
                   [57839709,'2021-01-08',3]],columns=['ID','DATE','QTD'])

def monthdelta(a,b):
    a1,a2,a3 = (int(k) for k in a.split('-'))
    b1,b2,b3 = (int(k) for k in b.split('-'))
    return (a1*12+a2) - (b1*12+b2)


startdate = {}
sums = {}
sumsqs = {}
num = {}
stdev = []
means = []
total = []
ind_max = []
ind_min = []
ind_maximum = 0
ind_minimum = 0

for row in df.T.iteritems():
    id = row[1]['ID']
    if id not in startdate:
        num[id] = 1
        startdate[id] = row[1]['DATE']
        sums[id] = row[1]['QTD']
        sumsqs[id] = row[1]['QTD'] * row[1]['QTD']
        means.append( row[1]['QTD'] )
        total.append( row[1]['QTD'] )
        stdev.append( 0 )
        ind_maximum = row[1]['QTD']
        ind_minimum = row[1]['QTD']
        ind_min.append( row[1]['QTD'] )
        ind_max.append( row[1]['QTD'] )
    else:
        num[id] += 1
        sums[id] += row[1]['QTD']
        sumsqs[id] += row[1]['QTD'] * row[1]['QTD']
        delta = monthdelta(row[1]['DATE'],startdate[id]) + 1
        means.append( sums[id] / delta )
        total.append( sums[id] )
        if delta == 1:
            stdev.append( 0 )
        else:
            stdev.append( np.sqrt((delta*sumsqs[id] - sums[id]*sums[id])/delta))
        if row[1]['QTD'] > ind_maximum:
            ind_max.append( row[1]['QTD'] )
            ind_maximum = row[1]['QTD']
        else: 
            ind_max.append( ind_maximum )
 
        if row[1]['QTD'] < ind_minimum:
            ind_min.append( row[1]['QTD'] )
            ind_minimum = row[1]['QTD']
        else:
            ind_min.append( ind_minimum )

df['MEAN'] = pd.Series(means)
df['STDEV'] = pd.Series(stdev)
df['TOTAL'] = pd.Series(total)
df['MAX'] = pd.Series(ind_max)
df['MIN'] = pd.Series(ind_min)
```

The code works and I get the following output:

```
    ID          DATE       QTD  MEAN        STDEV     TOTAL MAX MIN
0   58685991    2020-06-01  2   2.000000    0.000000    2   2   2
1   58685991    2020-06-01  1   3.000000    0.000000    3   2   1
2   58685991    2020-06-01  0   3.000000    0.000000    3   2   0
3   58685991    2020-12-05  7   1.428571    6.301927    10  7   0
4   57839709    2020-12-01  5   5.000000    0.000000    5   5   5
5   57839709    2021-01-08  3   4.000000    1.414214    8   5   3
```

The problem I am encountering is when I apply it to a big data set, some `ID's` get wrong feature values I can't seem to understand why? Some only have one entry with one `QTD` but get a higher than 1.0 mean and the total is very high as well. This problem occurs with other features as well.

Not sure if it is because I use a series and then decide to make a column on the data frame.
Is there a way this could be done by manipulating the data frame itself wit `.loc` and `.iloc`? Would this be a saffer way to work with the data? I am not very confortable with them so if an example could be provided would be great.

Comment: Can you clarify how 'TOTAL' is calculated?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: The `TOTAL` is the sum of all `QTD`. Wether if in an entry there is a `QTD` of one or more.

Comment: I assume the MRE is given since if the code is copy and pasted works fine. I don't have an example with `.loc` or `.iloc` because, as I explained, I am not very profiencient working with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the same logic implemented in a vectorized form (which is generally more efficient on large datasets):

```
# convert DATE to datetime
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

# calculate min, max, sum
df[['min', 'max', 'sum']] = (
    df
        .groupby('ID')['QTD']
        .expanding()
        .agg(['min', 'max', 'sum'])
        .reset_index('ID', drop=True))

# calculate delta
df['date_first'] = df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].transform('min')
df['delta'] = (
    (df['DATE'].dt.year - df['date_first'].dt.year) * 12 +
    (df['DATE'].dt.month - df['date_first'].dt.month) + 1)

# calculate sum of squares
df['qtd_sq'] = df['QTD']**2
df['sum_sq'] = df.groupby('ID')['qtd_sq'].cumsum()

# calculate standard deviation
df['stdev'] = np.where(
    df['delta']==1, 0,
    np.sqrt((df['delta']*df['sum_sq'] - df['sum']*df['sum']) / df['delta']))

# calculate means
df['means'] = df['sum'] / df['delta']

# drop temp columns
df = df.drop(columns=['delta', 'qtd_sq', 'sum_sq', 'date_first'])

df
```

Output:

```
         ID       DATE  QTD  min  max   sum     stdev     means
0  58685991 2020-06-01    2  2.0  2.0   2.0  0.000000  2.000000
1  58685991 2020-06-01    1  1.0  2.0   3.0  0.000000  3.000000
2  58685991 2020-06-01    0  0.0  2.0   3.0  0.000000  3.000000
3  58685991 2020-12-05    7  0.0  7.0  10.0  6.301927  1.428571
4  57839709 2020-12-01    5  5.0  5.0   5.0  0.000000  5.000000
5  57839709 2021-01-08    3  3.0  5.0   8.0  1.414214  4.000000
```

Comment: @HenryEcker Ah, yes, interesting... looks like `sum`, `min` and `max` are still OK, but `mean` and `std` are calculated with some different logic...

Comment: The `delta` is the number of months the `ID` has on the data set. I use it to calculate the mean and the standard deviation.

Comment: @Peter Updated the answer to calculate the values using your logic, but in a vectorized form, which will likely perform better on larger datasets

Comment: @perl On the big data set I get some NaN on the stdev. Can this be due to the fact that those `IDs` have several `QTD` every month? I think I can just fill them with zero and not lose the logic but I wanted to have your opinion as well.

Comment: @HenryEcker If I'm not missing something, with months it's a bit tricky, for example if I take `(pd.to_datetime(['2021-03-01']) - pd.to_datetime(['2021-01-01'])).astype('timedelta64[M]')` I would get 1, while the original `monthdelta` logic should give 2, right?

Comment: No you're correct. You'd have to wrap in an Offset which in the end probably wouldn't be any more clear. Good catch. =)

Comment: @HenryEcker I changed the delta column in my version for this (which worked fine) : `z = df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].transform.min()
df['delta']=( (df['DATE'].dt.year - z.dt.year)*12 + (df['DATE'].dt.month - z.dt.month)+1 )`

Comment: @Peter Interesting, there seem to be 2 options: either we have some QTDs that are NaN, or we get a negative value under np.sqrt(...). It should be relatively easy to debug: just remove the line dropping temporary columns, and find one of the rows where we have NaN for stdev

Comment: @perl what happens is that there are rows in which the sum_sq is equal to sum. Which then gives a sqrt below zero. That is weird because `sum_sq` should be the square of the `sum` in each row right? I did `df['sum_sq']=df['sum']**2` an it eliminated the NaN.

Comment: @Peter `sum_sq` is basically the sum of squares of QTDs, which is not the same as the square of sums. For example, if we have values [1, 1], the sum of squares is `1**2 + 1**2 = 2`, and the square of sum is `(1 + 1)**2 = 4`. I think that was your logic with `sumsqs` as well, right?

Comment: @perl Yes. So how come the sqrt is below zero? I don't understand. Is there some calculus wrong? For example doing the std formula I get `3*4 - 4*4 `. Because the `ID` did 3 `QTD` but they were in different days (on the same month) so they appear in different rows.

Comment: @Peter It's difficult to answer that without knowing more what you're trying to calculate, since what we call `stdev` here is not a regular standard deviation formula (which is `np.sqrt((x**2).mean() - x.mean()**2)`). We multiply by `delta` and we're taking sums instead of means, so the value inside `np.sqrt` strictly speaking doesn't have to be non-negative (as we have already seen, of course)

Comment: @perl What I try to calculate is the monthly standard deviation. I intend to have a incremantal standard deviation of `QTD` for each `ID` event. The same way there is an incremental monthly mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233031/discussion-between-perl-and-peter).